# GAM Deploy Tool

Tags: deployment, genexus, genexus-gam

When running Gam Deploy Tool in order to update GAM schema (from version 3.0.5 to 3.0.6) I get the following error:

> 2014-10-23 14:53:42,000 - [INF] Updating table SessionHistoryLogAtt . Started.
>   2014-10-23 14:53:42,000 - [INF] ERROR in ReorganizeSession : Type:GeneXus.Data.GxADODataException.Tentativa de carregar bibliotecas de cliente Oracle resultou em BadImageFormatException.  Esse problema ocorrerá ao executar em modo de 64 bits com componentes de cliente Oracle de 32 bits instalados.

Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Osmar

Try installing the 32 bits oracle client, as the following documentation suggests:
http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxpp001.aspx?15,4,61,O,E,0,,32396

Sabrina.